# Find minimum value in groups of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

In the SQL space (specifically T-SQL, SQL Server 2008), given this list of values:

```
    Status  Date
    ------  -----------------------
    ACT     2012-01-07 11:51:06.060
    ACT     2012-01-07 11:51:07.920
    ACT     2012-01-08 04:13:29.140
    NOS     2012-01-09 04:29:16.873
    ACT     2012-01-21 12:39:37.607         <-- THIS
    ACT     2012-01-21 12:40:03.840
    ACT     2012-05-02 16:27:17.370
    GRAD    2012-05-19 13:30:02.503
    GRAD    2013-09-03 22:58:48.750
```

Generated from this query:

```
    SELECT Status, Date
    FROM Account_History
    WHERE AccountNumber = '1234'
    ORDER BY Date
```

The status for this particular object started at ACT, then changed to NOS, then back to ACT, then to GRAD.

What is the best way to get the minimum date from the latest "group" of records where Status = 'ACT'?

Comment: I don't understand, what drives the need for ACT -- input?

Comment: Hogan: basically, yes.  I just want to know the date/time when the account was last changed to ACT.  The records after the point above marked THIS are just extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query that does this, by identifying the groups where the student statuses are the same and then using simple aggregation:

```
select top 1 StudentStatus, min(WhenLastChanged) as WhenLastChanged
from (SELECT StudentStatus, WhenLastChanged,
             (row_number() over (order by "date") -
              row_number() over (partition by studentstatus order by "date)
            ) as grp
      FROM Account_History
      WHERE AccountNumber = '1234'
    ) t
where StudentStatus = 'ACT'
group by StudentStatus, grp
order by WhenLastChanged desc;
```

The `row_number()` function assigns sequential numbers within groups of rows based on the `date`.  For your data, the two `row_numbers()` and their difference is:

```
Status  Date
------  -----------------------
ACT     2012-01-07 11:51:06.060    1      1      0
ACT     2012-01-07 11:51:07.920    2      2      0
ACT     2012-01-08 04:13:29.140    3      3      0
NOS     2012-01-09 04:29:16.873    4      1      3
ACT     2012-01-21 12:39:37.607    5      4      1
ACT     2012-01-21 12:40:03.840    6      5      1
ACT     2012-05-02 16:27:17.370    7      6      1
GRAD    2012-05-19 13:30:02.503    8      1      7
GRAD    2013-09-03 22:58:48.750    9      2      7
```

Notice the last row is constant for rows that have the same status.

The aggregation brings these together and chooses the latest (`top 1 . . . order by date desc`) of the first dates (`min(date)`).

EDIT:

The query is easy to tweak for multiple account numbers.  I probably should have written that way to begin with, except the final selection is trickier.  The results from this has the date for each status and account:

```
select StudentStatus, min(WhenLastChanged) as WhenLastChanged
from (SELECT StudentStatus, WhenLastChanged, AccountNumber
             (row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber order by WhenLastChanged) -
              row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber, studentstatus order by WhenLastChanged)
            ) as grp
      FROM Account_History
    ) t
where StudentStatus = 'ACT'
group by AccountNumber, StudentStatus, grp
order by WhenLastChanged desc;
```

But you can't get the last one per account quite so easily.  Another level of subqueries:

```
select AccountNumber, StudentStatus, WhenLastChanged
from (select AccountNumber, StudentStatus, min(WhenLastChanged) as WhenLastChanged,
             row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber, StudentStatus order by min(WhenLastChanged) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from (SELECT AccountNumber, StudentStatus, WhenLastChanged,
                   (row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber order by WhenLastChanged) -
                    row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber, studentstatus order by WhenLastChanged)
                  ) as grp
            FROM Account_History
          ) t
      where StudentStatus = 'ACT'
      group by AccountNumber, StudentStatus, grp
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This uses aggregation along with the window function `row_number()`.  This is assigning sequential numbers to the groups (after aggregation), with the last date for each account getting a value of 1 (`order by min(WhenLastChanged) desc`).  The outermost `select` then just chooses that row for each account.

Comment: I tweaked your query before I saw your edit (added WHERE clause) and it worked for me perfectly.  I would love to better understand this answer so I will research this.  To step it up, how might I approach this if I wanted to get multiple last changes to ACT by joining on a table with multiple account numbers?  In other words, I have a table with 3 account numbers and want to know the same information per account.  (Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this - let me know and I will be glad to move this.)

Comment: @TSFroggy - Take a look at my answer, it might be easier to grok using the CTEs.  I'm not sure which would be faster.

Comment: Hogan, I couldn't get your query to run, sorry.

Comment: @Gordon I wish I could vote up, but as you can see I'm a long time lurker, few time poster. I thank you for your very detailed and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Gordon edited your final query a bit to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Status], MIN([Date])
FROM Table_Name
WHERE [Status] = (SELECT [Status]
                  FROM Table_Name
                  WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date])
                                  FROM Table_Name)
                  )
GROUP BY  [Status]
```

Try here <kbd>[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac02f/1)</kbd>

Comment: missing some group by here.

Comment: If by "minimum date" the OP means earliest, this is what you want

Comment: @Hogan what's missing? Looks fine to me

Comment: What I have understood from question is to find the minimum date for a group where group is in the latest date. this query does exactly the same but returns a different row than what OP suggests that it should return.

Comment: @MBarnett as written this will get the min date for when he was a grad not an act

Comment: Wouldn't this return the `MIN` Date of `Status = 'GRAD'`.

Comment: @user2989408 yes it will because before you edited your question this is what you described in your requirement. now you have edited your question and your requirement as well.

Comment: @M.Ali I wasn't the one who asked/modified the question, but yes the requirement may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Hogan: basically, yes. I just want to know the date/time when the
>   account was last changed to ACT. The records after the point above
>   marked THIS are just extra.

Instead of just looking for act we can look for first time status changes and select act (and max) from that.

so... every time a status changes:

```
with rownumb as
(
   select *, row_number() OVER (order by date asc) as rn
)
select status, date
from rownumb A
join rownumb B on A.rn = B.rn-1
where a.status != b.status
```

now finding the max of the act items.

```
with rownumb as
(
   select *, row_number() OVER (order by date asc) as rn
), statuschange as
(
  select status, date
  from rownumb A
  join rownumb B on A.rn = B.rn-1
  where a.status != b.status
)
select max(date) 
from satuschange 
where status='Act'
```